# Proving that $1+x^py^{1-p} \le (1+x)^p(1+y)^{1-p}$

Tags: inequality

I'd like to show that $1+x^py^{1-p} \le (1+x)^p(1+y)^{1-p}$ for all $x,y \ge 0$ and $p \in [0,1]$. I started out by defining a function $f(x,y)=(1+x)^p(1+y)^{1-p}$ and checking for critical points, but there are none in the domain I'm interested in. I think I'm probably missing a slick application of Jensen's or Holder's inequalities, but so far a proof eludes me. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume $x,y>0$ to avoid $0^0$.

When $p=0$ or $p=1$, the inequality is trivial so let's suppose that $p\in(0,1)$. Let $r=\frac{1}{p}$ and $s=\frac{1}{1-p}$ so that $r,s>1$ and $\frac{1}{r}+\frac{1}{s}=1$. Holder's inequality then gives: for $X,Y\geq 0$,
$$
1+XY\leq(1^r+X^r)^{1/r}(1^s+Y^s)^{1/s}=(1+X^r)^p(1+Y^s)^{1-p}.
$$
Now, let $X=x^p=x^{1/r}$ and $Y=y^{1-p}=y^{1/s}$.